# Speed difference between ActiveCell.Offset() and Range()?

Tags: excel, vba

**Summary:** I'm looping through many rows of data and storing data from different columns in about 6 different variables each time through the loop

**Question:** Would I save a very significant amount of CPU cycles using `Range("A" & some iterator)` as opposed to `ActiveCell.Offset(some number)`? How much quicker is one than the other?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems like it would be very easy to test, but I'm guessing that's not going to make any perceptible difference (as long as you're not actually selecting each cell). EDIT: OK - second version is 2-3 times faster over a range covering 100k cells.

Comment: In many circumstances it's quicker to load the range into an array and cycle the array. Reading/writing to sheets is often the slowest operation so try and do 1 of each where possible.

Comment: @TimWilliams what did you mean by Second Version?

Comment: @Mike - You gave two examples (versions) of referring to cells - I meant the second one.  I tested a simple loop for each approach, using 100k rows: just checked the value in the cell, and didn't perform any other operations.

Comment: just as an aside, I would use `Range(` rather than `ActiveCell` just because I don't want an errant click messing up the results

Comment: What is your actual code? Typically slow loops can be avoided using `Find`, `AutoFilter`, `SpecialCells` or as per ooo's comment, arrays

Comment: @brettdj - `Advanced filter` is also a good one. I always find `MATCH` far quicker than `FIND` but use `On error resume next: t = 0 : t = Worksheetfunction.Match(<whatever>) : On error goto 0 : If t = 0 then debug.Print "No Match"`

Comment: @ooo For a single value thats true, but `FIND` can come into its own for multiple values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Out of sheer boredom and a little curiosity I put together a crude timer for various methods to cycle 100,000 Excel cells.

Ideally you should run each a number of times and take the average but it gives you a rough outline of speed.

On my machine this is what I get

[image]

```
Option Explicit

#If Win64 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long
#Else
    Public Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long
#End If

Sub TestSpeedofReadingCells()
Dim tcStart As Long
Dim tcEnd As Long
Dim temp As Variant

Dim i As Long
Dim rngobject As Range
Dim rngItem As Range
Dim rngArray() As Variant
Const rowsToRead As Long = 100000


    '***Read individual cells using .Range
    With Sheet1
        tcStart = GetTickCount
        For i = 1 To rowsToRead
            temp = .Range("A" & i).Value
        Next i
        tcEnd = GetTickCount
        Debug.Print "Time1: " & tcEnd - tcStart
    End With

    '***Read individual cells using .Range & screenupdating off
    With Sheet1
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        tcStart = GetTickCount
        For i = 1 To rowsToRead
            temp = .Range("A" & i).Value
        Next i
        tcEnd = GetTickCount
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Debug.Print "Time1a: " & tcEnd - tcStart
    End With

    '***Read individual cells using .Range & screenupdating off & using value2
    With Sheet1
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        tcStart = GetTickCount
        For i = 1 To rowsToRead
            temp = .Range("A" & i).Value2
        Next i
        tcEnd = GetTickCount
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Debug.Print "Time1b: " & tcEnd - tcStart
    End With

    '***Read individual cells using range object
    With Sheet1
        Set rngobject = .Range("A1:A" & rowsToRead)
        tcStart = GetTickCount
        For Each rngItem In rngobject
            temp = rngItem
        Next rngItem
        tcEnd = GetTickCount
        Debug.Print "Time2: " & tcEnd - tcStart
    End With

    '***Read individual cells using activecell
    With Sheet1
        tcStart = GetTickCount
        .Range("A1").Select
        For i = 1 To rowsToRead
            temp = ActiveCell.Offset(i - 1, 0).Value
        Next i
        tcEnd = GetTickCount
        Debug.Print "Time3: " & tcEnd - tcStart
    End With

    '***Read individual cells using activecell & screenupdating off
    With Sheet1
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        tcStart = GetTickCount
        .Range("A1").Select
        For i = 1 To rowsToRead
            temp = ActiveCell.Offset(i - 1, 0).Value
        Next i
        tcEnd = GetTickCount
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Debug.Print "Time3a: " & tcEnd - tcStart
    End With

    '***Read individual cells using array
    With Sheet1
        tcStart = GetTickCount
        rngArray = .Range("A1:A" & rowsToRead).Value
        For i = 1 To rowsToRead 'should really use Lbound to Ubound but only example
            temp = rngArray(i, 1)
        Next i
        tcEnd = GetTickCount
        Debug.Print "Time4: " & tcEnd - tcStart
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: +1. Nice answer, I didn't realize how ridiculously faster those differences are. Definitely will be using the later in all future applications rather than scanning through.

Comment: It doesn't look like case 2 and 4 even get the value in the loop. Seems like it would help explain why there's such a difference.